# Is it possible to use java.net.http with VSCode & Java Extension Plugin only?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am collaborating with others and am using Visual Studio Code for doing the Java projects. As we are only sharing the source `.java` files only, I have no idea on how to run the code from others that imports java.net.http module. How should I run the code as VSCode is reporting problems?

Edit: `javac --version` gives javac 1.8.0_332 which might be the problem.
Steps to reproduce:

1. open a folder
2. create a java file
3. import java.net.http.HttpClient;
4. error: "The import java.net.http cannot be resolved"

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with enough details to recreate the problem. For example, what is the (minimal) code needed to cause the problem? (Add the formatted code to your question.) What is the actual problem? (Show us the text of any errors.) What version of Java are you using? (`java.net.http` was introduced in Java version 11.) How have you set up your project in VS Code?

Comment: What means "VSCode is reporting problems". Provide some more details https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by andrewJames, `java.net.http` was introduced in Java version 11. Setup VS Code with JDK-17 under Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) - Java: Configure Java Runtime resolve the issue. You might need to download JDK 11+ installer from online.

Reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_configure-jdk